# How to show userID (or loginname) in Survey?

Tags: survey-list, survey

We are using SP2013 on-premise. We want to use OOTB survey template to do some survey. After some tests, I understood we can export the results to Excel. The users' **Display name** will be exported.

However, I don't need the **Display name**. I need the **userID** (e.g. domain.com\johndoe or just johndoe). Can I customize it without PowerShell access?

Comment: You might have to run a workflow to set user id in additional text field based on User column and then use it report extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways by setting the value of an SP column.

1: Workflow to set a text field with the string of the person who created the item. Or if that does not work you can set it to Domain Name + Login by using the string constructer (the ... button).

[image]

2: Alternatively you should also be able to set a SP field using JS and by getting current SP.user details. Unless needed have this field hidden so to the user it looks like nothing is different.

I recommend method 1.